# IIS - the request is rejected by HTTP filter when there are european char in the url

Tags: http, url, filter, iis-6, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a web api application that returns valid post-codes for given city. The application is hosted on WinServer 2008 R2, IIS 6.1.

Application works fine as long as there are no European-char (ä,ß,æ,ø,å) in the URL.
But with any special/European-char in URL I get the following error message:

Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217)

E.g. for working URL: edu.web/Api/PostCode/Heidenau

E.g. for non-working URL: edu.web/Api/PostCode/Heidehäuser

E.g. for non-working URL with URL encoding: edu.web/Api/PostCode/Heideh%C3%A4user

How to configure the IIS to accept european chars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by involving our system administrator.
All Internet requests are passed through **ISA server** (Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway) which by default filters all requests with special characters before they hit our Webservers.

After we changed the [Configuration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837865#MT2), everything started working as intended.